# Executing an Excel package worksheets with different table structure from SSIS to different tables in SSMS dynamically?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms, execute, dataflow

Can I execute an Excel package worksheets with different table structure from SSIS to different tables in SSMS  dynamically ?

I have an excel file with 3 worksheets. I want to process those worksheets into one database in SSMS but each to their own table. what will be the best practice processing this file? i'm new to SSIS . Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the tables already available in the database or do they have to be created in SSIS? Either way, this could help you: https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/ssis-importing-a-file-with-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 0):

You could, suppose you have target set already in database. there is one properties called **openrowset** in the advanced properties for excel source. you could specify which sheet to be loaded as well as the columns.

For example, Sheet1$A1:Z, which will load data from sheet1 A column to Z, start from row #1 if you did not check header row as row #1